# jquery overlay - how to custom close

Tags: jquery, overlay

I'm having trouble creating a custom close button for my overlay.  Here's what the html of my dialog looks like

```
<div id="new-window">
<div class="close">Custom Close Button</div>
</div>
```

Here's my javascript code

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({

        effect: 'apple',
        speed: 'fast',
        onBeforeLoad: function() {

                // grab wrapper element inside content
                var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

                // load the page specified in the trigger
                wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

});
```

The dialog appears fine.  But everytime I click on "Custom Close Button" nothing happens.  I can only close the dialog by pressing escape key.

This is the documentation I tried to follow.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html#close

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized you can close an overlay like this:

```
$(selectorforelementthatopennedtheoverlay).overlay().close();
```

So something like this worked for me:

```
$('.close').click(function() {$("a[rel]").overlay().close();})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding a custom click event to the close button using pure jquery.

And maybe you could add additional tags to your question because overlay is not core jquery